# Reversing conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If

$$
P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}
$$

then can the conditional probability be reversed ?

So that :

$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}
$$

Comment: Just change the $P(A)$ in the denominator to $P(B)$, too.

Comment: Your "If" condition is always true and, of course, by symmetry, it can be reversed.

Comment: Both equations are true only if $P(A)=P(B)\neq 0$